# Archiving (old) application data in (Oracle) Database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, archive

I have a fairly large Business Application related to Order Management, whose data is in Oracle Database.

All data can be related to Orders.
Now, the data size is huge, millions of records in tables - thereby slowing down my application SQL Queries.

I am planning a replica schema of my main 'Order Schema', say 'Archive Order Schema'.
And write SQL Queries to move (old order) data from main to archival schema, one (old) Order at a time.

But the SQL Queries are quite slow, and to move all data of a (old) Order (across so many tables), takes very long time.

Any design / approach / optimization inputs are welcome.

Comment: The amount of data shouldn't be a major issue for your application's individual prder processing  if you have appropriate indexes etc. Have you established where and why it is slow? Would partitioning be appropriate? And why are you moving one record at a time, rather than all at once, or at least in baches?

Comment: I'm with @AlexPoole, I myself have a 500GB database table that contains billions of rows, but all of my SELECT queries return in under 20ms because I have good indexing. If you want to archive data to save space, that's fine - but doing it for performance means you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: millions of rows is not considered "huge". It's usually not even considered "big" nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as the others have noted, a few million lines in Order Management tables is nothing. Even a few hundred million rows or billions of rows is not a challenge. We manage an EBS with larger Order Management tables without much effort. Make sure you are gathering schema statistics using the EBS Concurrent Request (not DBA tools); although you might check with your DBA on rebuilding your indexes. Also make sure you are patched up as Oracle EBS patches often include different indexes to improve performance from logged problems. Run some AWS stats or even a SQL trace to find your bottle necks and work with Oracle Support.

Next, **DO NOT** use SQL to archive seeded tables. You *will* have problems and Oracle will not help you then. You should instead do some research and use Oracle's **built in** and supported archive and purge processes. Start by reading Note 752322.1 on My Oracle Support, it will point you to managing your data in Order Management.

Comment: Wolf> Is there a direct link to: Note 752322.1   Not sure how to access it.

Comment: @Jasper You need an [Oracle Support](https://support.oracle.com) account to get to the article. If your E-Business Suite is in support you should have an account. You definitely want one, I can't imaging supporting Oracle Applications without access to the Oracle knowledge base on MOS. But I want to reiterate that there are built-in archive and purge processes in Oracle Apps, that will manage all dependencies, and maintain your data integrity.

Comment: @Jasper This is the direct link: [Reducing Your Oracle E-Business Suite Data Footprint using Archiving, Purging, and Information Lifecycle Management](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=752322.1)

Comment: Wolf > I guess DBAs would have access to such Oracle support accounts. Am not one and do not have it, so unable to read it. I wish someone would post this information somewhere public too. I will search on these lines.

Comment: If your organization has a current support contract with Oracle, all you need is your CSI (Customer Support Identifier) and you can create an account on My Oracle Support. Normally analysts, developers, super users and DBA's would have accounts; so you should be allowed to as well. Ask your department manager.